# Blocking a visitor even if the browser has cleaned

Tags: node.js

I've programmed a chat application with Node.js, ExpressJs and Socket.io
so I want to block a user who violate the chat terms, but the current methods of blocking a user is not useful! It can be bypassed if the user has experiences in the computer, The blocking methods is either blocking the user account, blocking by inserting data in his browser (cookies/sessions) or blocking his IP address.

All of these can be bypassed easily!

So, What I want to do is blocking the user's computer from entering the chat, I've tried to google about getting the CPU/Hard disk unique id but it seems to be impossible!

So, what is the real solution? How can I block a visitor's device from entering my website?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint

Comment: Whatever countermeasure you devise can be circumvented by a tech savvy user; So don't expect a silver bullet. Granted you can make it harder but at some point you'll get diminishing returns. Is your chat application already that popular that it warrants spending time on this?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Ok, I'm checking it now. thanks :)

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Yes I know that all the protecting methods can be bypassed by the user, but not any user can bypass it, I want to make it harder than the current.